# Preserving reference in properties assigned to parameters

Tags: c#, winforms, wizard, ref

I am putting together a wizard that has multiple pages that the user is shown. I need one page to be able access data from a user choice on a previous page. My idea was to just pass in a parameter by reference into the constructors of both pages, and then assign a property to that parameter, but the change isn't persisting between pages. I'm assuming it means I am incorrectly using ref.
I cannot pass data directly to the methods themselves as they are controlled by the wizard host.

Host initialization:

```
    WizardHost host = new WizardHost();
    using (host)
    {
        host.Text = Migration.Properties.Resources.AppName;
        host.ShowFirstButton = false;
        host.ShowLastButton = false;
        host.WizardCompleted += new WizardHost.WizardCompletedEventHandler(this.Host_WizardCompleted);

        Reference<DBManip> dbControllerRef = new Reference<DBManip>();
        bool exportPathActive = false;

        host.WizardPages.Add(1, new Page1());
        host.WizardPages.Add(2, new Page2(dbControllerRef));
        host.WizardPages.Add(3, new Page3(dbControllerRef, ref exportPathActive));
        host.WizardPages.Add(4, new Page4(dbControllerRef, ref exportPathActive));
        host.WizardPages.Add(5, new Page5());
        host.LoadWizard();
        host.ShowDialog();
```

Page where ref is linked with property:

```
    public Page3(Reference<DBManip> dbControllerRef, ref bool exportPathActive)
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.DBControllerRef = dbControllerRef;
        this.Page3Body.Text = Migration.Properties.Resources.Page3Body;
        this.ExportPathActiveRef = exportPathActive;
    }

    public Reference<DBManip> DBControllerRef
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
```

If I modify exportPathActive in the constructor that modification is preserved in the next page, but a property that is assigned to the passed parameter doesn't preserve the reference. I'm pretty new to C#, so this is probably something silly I'm missing, but I can't find it on Google or looking around SO.

Comment: you might be able to store the info in the session variable.

Comment: The word `page` is a little misleading since the question is tagged `winforms`.

Comment: @ScottHannen How is the word page misleading? These are pages of the wizard within a winforms project.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs, that looks like it might work, but is it accepted practice? It seems pretty hacky.

Comment: "Misleading" is the wrong word. You didn't mislead anyone - your question is correctly tagged. We see "page": and think "web," but if we look at the tag it's clear that it's not a web app.

Comment: @AdrianSmith well, it may leave a bad taste in your mouth, but... how much is the business going to appreciate the extra time to do it the "right" way, and what benefit does it bring you?  Ultimately, you have to decide how much effort it's worth.  Sometimes the hacky way is the most practical. my $.02.  You might also consider a `MemoryCache` construct.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs, I'm making a winforms application, are session variables even a tool in winforms?

Comment: Whups I missed that.  thought it was webforms.  If it's winforms, why not just stick it into a variable with adequate scope?

Answer (score 0):

I have decided on just making a class called PersistentData with a property called ExportPathActive, and then passing that. It works well and I can expand it to hold more data if needed. I'll wait to approve this in case a more elegant approach is posted.

The Class:

```
/// <summary>
/// A store to pass data between pages.
/// </summary>
public class PersistentData
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="PersistentData"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public PersistentData()
    {
        this.ExportPathActive = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether [export path active].
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///   <c>true</c> if [export path active]; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </value>
    public bool ExportPathActive { get; set; }
}
```